# Project naming for C# version

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions

I am translating a C++ project to C#. Say the original C++ project name is called **Company.Project.SubProject**. What is a good name for C# version? Please advise, thanks.

EDIT:
Since if both C++ and C# projects are all called **Company.Project.SubProject**, it would be a bit confusing to distinguish them in TFS or so.

Comment: What is wrong with following the same convention? It is quite common even in the C# world.

Comment: You mean, should it be `Company.ProjectCS.SubProject`, `Company.Project.CShard.SubProject`, or something else?

Comment: Yea, things like that. Since there will be many projects being translated, using same name will make it harder to distinguish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The project should be called "SubProject".
- The project file should be called "SubProject.csproj".
- The namespace should be called "Company.Project.SubProject".
- The solution containing the project should probably be called "Project".